# Disabling landscape mode for a few pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, landscape-portrait

I've build my responsive website using bootstrap.Its working fine with the landscape as well as potrait mode in all devices.
My requirement states that there are a few pages which should open up in only potrait mode whereas rest of the pages opens in both modes,so i have to disable landscape for only a few pages.How can i do that?
I'm using twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

This might help in the required pages:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
        if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
            document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        }
    });
</script>
```